# When will the Sistine Chapel open after the Papal Conclave?

Tags: sightseeing, religion, events, vatican-city

The Sistine Chapel is now closed for visitors.

When will it reopen after a pope is elected?
My question is does anyone know how many days after the conclave is done, it is re-opened?

Comment: great question!

Comment: In the meantime, have a look at the [VR version of the Sistine Chapel](http://www.vatican.va/various/cappelle/sistina_vr/index.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various news articles I read about this (eg [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2013/03/08/us-pope-succession-security-idUSBRE9270SM20130308) and [Catholic.org](http://www.catholic.org/hf/faith/story.php?id=50010)) said that they installed a false floor and the stoves. They needed about a week to do that plus sweep for bugs, and that work will need to be undone once the conclave is finished. They will be voting for an unknown amount of time ([Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/03/08/papal-conclave-new-pope-vatican_n_2806379.html)) : a week is a good guess I suppose. If you plan to visit more than two weeks from the start of the conclave on March 12th, it should be open. Less than a week from now, it won't be. I am not sure how we can predict with more precision than that.

Comment: Apparently they only voted for two days :)

Answer (score 10):

[Notice:
The Sistine Chapel reopens](http://mv.vatican.va/3_EN/pages/MV_Home.html)

As the Conclave has now come to an end with the election of Pope Francis, the Sistine Chapel will reopen for visits by the public on Monday 18 March at 9am. It will also again be possible to visit the Borgia Apartment and the Collection of Modern Religious Art.

Comment: It would be great if you have a reference for that answer.